# Assigning argv for testing purpose

Tags: c++

I have to modify previously written C++ code and for program takes some command line arguments.
Other people will be doing review and will be testing this code, to ease them, I have written this...

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // To do testing just uncomment the below line.
#define TESTING
#ifdef TESTING  
    argc = ARGUMENT_COUNT;
    argv[1] = new char[strlen(INPUT_FILE) + 1 ];
    strcpy(argv[1], INPUT_FILE);
    argv[2] = new char[strlen(MERGE_FILE) + 1 ];
    strcpy(argv[2], MERGE_FILE);
    .
    .
    .
#endif
```

My question: is there any other better way to handle this type of testing where command line is involved and the same variable `argv` is used everywhere.

Note: I dont have IDE support. I am using vi editor on a remote server.

Comment: usually you can provide args through your IDE.

Comment: Create a script which runs your program with the specified arguments?

Comment: No IDE... I am logging into remote server to do coding. And I have to test there only.

Comment: May I suggest you use a proper testing framework for your OS/environment? Don't roll your own, testing is a solved problem.

Comment: what is `ARGUMENT_COUNT` `INPUT_FILE` and `MERGE_FILE`? are they defined in compiler flags?

Comment: I would consider using a script.

Comment: Your suggested solution risks undefined behaviour. For example if argc initially was 3 and you write a new pointer to argv[5], you are writing out of bounds.

Comment: *is there any other better way to handle this type of testing where command line is involved and the same variable `argv` is used everywhere.*  Yes.  Pass different command-line arguments appropriate for your testing. That's why command-line arguments exist - so you can pass different things to your process.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code that processes the command line arguments into a separate function, maybe even in a method in a class that stores the values and provides them to your application.
Then, call this function/method from your `main()` function. Finally, implement test program(s) with test cases/functions which also call the function with the prepared test data and check for the expected result.

This way, production implementation and tests are clearly separated, no need to use a hack to provide the test data etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your argv can be const, you can create a new `argv` and replace the origin one like this.

---

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
    // To do testing just uncomment the below line.
#define TESTING
#ifdef TESTING
    const char* args[]={
       "arg 1","arg 2","arg 3",nullptr
    };
    argc = sizeof(args)/sizeof(char*);
    argv = args;
#endif
}
```

---

If it's for test propose, use test framework is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard *does* allow you to change `argc` and `argv`. Don't forget to release the memory you've allocate with `new[]` though.

But a better alternative would be to pass the arguments via your IDE or via a start-up script, rather than hack the code in this way.

Note that the behaviour of calling `main` from itself (even indirectly; i.e. via another function) is *undefined* in C++. So don't create a solution that does that.

For testing, I use the suite available in Boost. See www.boost.org.

Comment: No third party lib for security purpose...:-)

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that you're allowed to change the `argc` argument **even** by the language standard. There's nothing that restricts you from changing the value of an input argument. The contents of the memory block pointed by `argv` - well that's indeed "immutable".

Comment: "Well I'm pretty sure that you're allowed to change the argc argument even by the language standard". Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And the strings can be modified too. (It's not read-only memory). Obviously you can't write beyond their length, but you can point to newly created strings.

Comment: No, as I recall the strings can't be modified. The local arguments can be modified of course.

Comment: They *certainly* can in C99. I'll check C++ when I get a moment.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use a testing framework, but if I were to roll my own testing I would probably abstract command line arguments. Create a class that parses and holds the arguments. Use dependency injection to send either argv or your testing data to the constructor.